# POWER BI - Create a measure to compare Forecast vs Sales

Tags: powerbi, dax

Create a measure to compare forecast vs sales in power BI.

The logic is that at the beginning of Jan. 2018 it is forecasted the sales for the whole year and the amount of pcs sold in Jan. 2018 is only known in Feb. 2018 (next month's file). As an example, we are in Nov. 2018 and it is known how many pcs were sold in the previous months. I want to create a table to compare forecast vs sales.

[My dataset looks like the figure below. It is marked in red the historical data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcmDy.png)

[An example of a power BI matrix that I am trying to create by dividing forecast by sales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lbjw.png)

Comment: What does your data table look like?

Comment: All red circles are actual sales and the rest are sales plan. Above table, Rows and columns are months. The comparison shows the delta between sales plan vs actual sales. Is it clear?

Comment: How is your source data structured? (before it gets loaded into report view). What exactly are you trying to achieve, a comparison between budgeted and actual sales?

Comment: I edited my post with more detailed information. I am trying to create a power bi matrix that measures the difference between forecast and actual sales. Would you have any suggestion?

Comment: You still haven't shown your SOURCE data.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to normalize your data source. This may look something like:

[image: normalized source data]

Now you can create some measures. Create a `Forecast Qty` measure:

```
Forecast Qty:=CALCULATE ( 
    SUM ( SourceTable[Qty] ),
    SourceTable[Type] = "Forecast"
)
```

A `Sold Qty` measure:

```
Sold Qty:=CALCULATE ( 
    SUM ( SourceTable[Qty] ),
    SourceTable[Type] = "Sold"
)
```

And a `Sales % Forecast` Measure:

```
Sales % Forecast:=DIVIDE ( 
    [Sold Qty],
    [Forecast Qty],
    BLANK()
)
```

Now you can lay out your visualisation as you choose. For example:

[image: example output]